# How to open an Excel file (97-2003) that is password protected, without Microsoft Office Interop

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core

The software I'm currently working on uses Microsoft Office Interop to read and write Excel files (97-2003). We want to get rid of Microsoft Office Interop because it forces the user to have Office installed and it's very slow.

Upgrading to the more recent 2007+ format (.xlsx) is not an alternative because the software has to be able to read the .xls files our customers are currently using.

I've looked into multiple librairies, like NPOI, ExcelLibrary, LibXL, IronXL and more, but none of these seem to be able to open a password protected **workbook**.
The only way I found to open a protected .xls workbook is with very expensive libraries, and there are not a lot of them. I know the password to open the Excel file.

Am I missing any ways to open an Excel file (.xls 97-2003) with a password protected workbook?

EDIT:
We ended up buying [FlexCel for .NET](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp). So far I am satisfied with the product, the price is not so bad and it seems to be working pretty good! It is much faster than Microsoft Office interop.

I'm still very surprised that I couldn't find a free and open source solution.

Comment: See work around on following page : https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: @jdweng I don't think this can work, from the link you provided: *If the Excel workbook is protected by a password, you cannot open it for data access, even by supplying the correct password with your connection string. If you try, you receive the following error message: "Could not decrypt file."*

The work around provided is not an option, the user does not have to know the password

Comment: You would need to create a shortcut that contained the password.

Comment: Technically, nothing prevents you from implementing the decryption yourself, as the details are documented in the [MS-XLS spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/cd03cb5f-ca02-4934-a391-bb674cb8aa06) an the [MS-OFFCRYPTO spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-offcrypto/3c34d72a-1a61-4b52-a893-196f9157f083). Of course, taking time into account, this is likely more expensive than just buying one of those libraries that's already done just that. There's probably no free lunch here, if using Excel itself is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Free Spire.XLS](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-xls-component.html), you can load a password protected .xls/.xlsx file with the following code:

```
using Spire.Xls;

namespace OpenPasswordProtectedExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            //Specify the open password
            workbook.OpenPassword = "your password";
            //Load the .xls file
            workbook.LoadFromFile("Input.xls");
            //Load the .xlsx file
            //workbook.LoadFromFile("Input.xlsx");

            //Do something you want
            //.....

            workbook.SaveToFile("output.xls", ExcelVersion.Version97to2003);
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you are limited to 200 rows per sheet and 5 worksheets per workbook if you are loading/saving an .xls file; this limitation does not apply to .xlsx files.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are using .xls files that have more than 200 rows per sheet and 5 worksheets. Spire.XLS was one of my possible paid options. Thanks for your answer!